# Sum array values to hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array like

```
[
    [358, 202102, 5],
    [358, 202112, 5],
    [358, 202102, 10],
    [311, 202103, 5],
    [311, 202101, 1],
    [311, 202101, 1],
    [311, 202115, 8],
    [311, 202101, 1],
    [311, 202101, 1]
]
```

I need a hash like this:

```
{
    358 => { 
        202102 => 15,
        202112 => 5
    },
    311 => {
        202103 => 5,
        202101 => 4,
        202115 => 8
    }
}
```

The order does not matter. Only the third values from each row of the array must be added up.

Comment: Is this `Array` structure 100% guaranteed?

Comment: @engineersmnky yes

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: A small suggestion: if you attach a variable to all example inputs (e.g., `a = [[358, 202102, 5],...]`) readers can refer to those variables in their answers and comments without having to define them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this using [`Enumberable#each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) as follows

```
a = [
    [358, 202102, 5],
    [358, 202112, 5],
    [358, 202102, 10],
    [311, 202103, 5],
    [311, 202101, 1],
    [311, 202101, 1],
    [311, 202115, 8],
    [311, 202101, 1],
    [311, 202101, 1]
]

a.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(0)}) do |(k1,k2,val), obj| 
  obj[k1][k2] += val 
end 
# => {358=>{202102=>15, 202112=>5}, 311=>{202103=>5, 202101=>4, 202115=>8}}
```

What this does is iterates over the Array (`a`) with an accumulator Object (`obj`).

This object is a `Hash` with a default proc where every time a new key is added its value is assigned as a new Hash with a default value of 0.

In the block arguments we deconstruct the Array into 3 arguments `(k1,k2,val)` so on first pass it would look something like this:

```
k1 = 358
k2 = 202102
val = 5 
obj[k1] 
#=> {358=> {}} 
obj[k1][k2] 
#=> {358 => {202102 => 0 }}
obj[k1][k2] += val
obj
#=> {358 => {202102 => 5 }}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use the methods [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) and [Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employ blocks to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. See the docs for definitions of the three block variables. I've used an underscore for the first block variables (the common key of the hashes being merged) to signify that it is not used in the block calculation.

```
a = [
    [358, 202102, 5],
    [358, 202112, 5],
    [358, 202102, 10],
    [311, 202103, 5],
    [311, 202101, 1],
    [311, 202101, 1],
    [311, 202115, 8],
    [311, 202101, 1],
    [311, 202101, 1]
]
```

```
a.each_with_object({}) do |(x,y,n),h|
  h.update(x=>{y=>n}) do |_,old1,new1|
    old1.merge(new1) { |_,old2,new2| old2+new2 }
  end
end
  #=> {358=>{202102=>15, 202112=>5}, 311=>{202103=>5, 202101=>4, 202115=>8}}
```

Comment: Only comment purely from a readability standpoint is that you distinguished `o` and `n` in the merge context (`oo` and `nn` respectively); however `n` already has an outer context as well as in `|(x,y,n),h|` so a further distinction could be valuable.

Comment: Sorry I was disingenuous I have a secondary comment `h` does not need to be defined using the block syntax for `Hash`; literal `{}` would be sufficient. You are not actually utilizing the default proc because first pass creates a nested Hash via `update`.

Comment: @engineersmnky, both good points; I did an edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

At first I create a hash of hashes with the default value 0. After that I just add the values of the hash of hashes up based on the last value in the array.

```rb
aoa =
[
    [358, 202102, 5],
    [358, 202112, 5],
    [358, 202102, 10],
    [311, 202103, 5],
    [311, 202101, 1],
    [311, 202101, 1],
    [311, 202115, 8],
    [311, 202101, 1],
    [311, 202101, 1]
]


hash = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(0) }
aoa.each { |ary|  hash[ary[0]][ary[1]] += ary[2]}

pp hash
```

output:

```
{358=>{202102=>15, 202112=>5}, 311=>{202103=>5, 202101=>4, 202115=>8}}
```